# Power VDDUSB on STM32 with 1.8V power supply

Tags: power-supply, stm32

I'm working on a STM32WB device which is always powered by battery or preferrably USB, if available, and a 1.8V power supply.

For the USB peripheral to be operational, VDDUSB must be supplied by a 3.3V supply. For that, i am using a 3.3V LDO that is enabled when USB is connected.

The STM32WB datasheet says:

> When VDD < 1 V the other power supplies (VDDA, VDDUSB and VLCD) must remain below VDD + 0.3 V

This is a non issue, when the STM32WB is already powered and supplied with a stable 1.8V.
However, when the battery is missing/empty and USB is being plugged in, the 1.8V power supply takes a couple of 100 micro seconds (~400us) to start up, while the 3.3V LDO starts up nearly instantly (few us). That means, there is a time frame where the *must remain below VDD + 0.3 V* part is not fullfilled for VDDUSB.

[image]

To combat that, i've been thinking of controlling the LDO enable with the STM32WB, like:

[image]

Or alternatively, use a voltage supervisor and only enable the LDO when the 1.8V rail is above 1.6V (DOUT is an open drain output):

[image]

I've also seen schematics that just connect 3.3V to VDDUSB, even when it may violate the condition in the datasheet.

Am i thinking too much into this? What would be the proper way to deal with this?